# Open system call failure

Tags: linux

After i call open() system call as

```
fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY, 0);
printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
if (fd < 0)
   perror("open");
```

i get fd = -2 and the perror("open") prints "Success"!!!

What does this mean, and why it happens?

Ok, i decided to test my code differently, like this:

```
if ((fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY, 0)) >= 0) {
  /* do smthg */
}
else {
  perror("open");
  printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
}
```

I think that the last portion of code i suggested, doesn't conflict from the in-between functions alternation of errno's value, but i'm still getting fd=-2 (???) and perror() prints "Success".!

Comment: Perhaps you have some typo or another call inbetween open and your perror. Show the full snippet of code that exhibits this behavior

Answer (score 3):

Something is resetting errno inside printf. Try commenting it out and you'll see something meaningful from perror.

Answer (score 3):

From the [errno](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) manpage:

> A common mistake is to do
>
> ```
>        if (somecall() == -1) {
>            printf("somecall() failed\n");
>            if (errno == ...) { ... }
>        }
> ```
>
> where errno no longer needs to have the value it had upon return from somecall() (i.e., it may have been changed by the printf(3)).  If the value of errno should be preserved across a library call, it must be  saved:
>
> ```
>        if (somecall() == -1) {
>            int errsv = errno;
>            printf("somecall() failed\n");
>            if (errsv == ...) { ... }
>        }
> ```

Comment: You still would need to convince `perror` to print the message for the saved `errsv` value somehow.

Comment: @Ben: Just assign it back with `errno = errsv;`

Comment: @Ben: or call `strerror(errsv)` (or better, use `strerror_r`) to get an error string that you can pass to `printf`

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage for "open"

> #### Return Value
>
> open() and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1  if  an  error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).

You'll notice that -2 is not the -1 that's supposed to be returned on failure, though the manpage does also say

> Given a pathname for a file, open() returns a file descriptor, a small, nonnegative integer  for  use  in  subsequent  system  calls

Comment: ok i have already read these and my main question is what does -2 means? Because if i do not interfere the perror between two functions i still get fd=-2 and perror() prints Success.

Comment: @user466825: I'm also befuddled.

Comment: Strange indeed, unless you have declared fd as a char, or even a short instead of an int, or have a buffer overflow or similar somewhere You should ,however, call open with only 2 arguments though. Only call open() with 3 arguments if you use the O_CREAT flag

Comment: if i use two arguments in open() syscall i get a compiler error: error: too few arguments to function ‘open’

Comment: @user466825 Then something really weird is going on, you don't have the proper prototype of the open() function from the standard headers. You should post a complete compilable example where you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The error code of the last call is stored in the `errno` global variable. `perror` uses this error code to lookup an error message string. When you get to `perror("open")` you are reading the error set by the call to `printf`. There wasn't an error printing your `fd=...` message so the error code is set to 0 which is `Success`. You should either save the error code like:

```
fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY, 0);
prev_error = errno;
printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
errno = prev_error;
if (fd < 0) perror("open");
```

or just re-order the code so that `perror` is called before `printf`.

Comment: Is error writable?  I thought it was a macro that can evaluate to a function call.

Comment: "errno  is  defined  by  the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type int , and must not be explicitly declared; errno may  be  a  macro. errno  is  thread-local;  setting  it in one thread does not affect its  value in any other thread." (from the manpage) It seems it can be a macro that **makes** a function call, but it would be something like `#define errno (*get_my_thread_local_errno())`, and because of the pointer dereference, it's assignable.

Comment: @Ben errno is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type int; it may be a macro but it must be an lvalue. That is, it could be a macro like `#define errno (*get_errno_location())` where `get_errno_location()` returns a pointer.